# My functions in R package using Rcpp and snowfall are slower than not in the package

Tags: rcpp, r-package, snowfall

I am developing an R package that uses mainly Rcpp, RcppArmadillo and snowfall (for parallel computing). It passed both `devtools::check' and 'devtools::check_rhub()'. However, I noticed that my code is slower in the package and would like to close the gap between the two. For example,

This is the `system.time()` result for running my code in the package.

**user  system elapsed 

18.72 31.12  135.56**

On the other hand, here is the `system.time()` result running my code normally outside of the package.

**user  system elapsed

4.23   2.98   102.18**

In addition, I also profiled (`profvis`) both and noticed a significantly longer time for `sfLapply`(for parallel computing) in the package environment. Here I provide a short summary of my code structure between the two. If needed, I'll add a link to my github code page.

### Code in package

The cpp functions are built into a DLL.

```
foo = function(...,core=10){

  sfInit(parallel=TRUE,cpus=core) ## set number of cores for parallel computing
  sfClusterSetupRNG( type="RNGstream",seed=cluster_seed) ## set cluster seed for reproducibility

  ## read inputs and set parameters
   .
   .
   .
  sfExport(list=ls()) ##exporting parameters to cores

  node = 0:(core-1)  

  print(system.time({

  for(i in 1:iter){

       ## update_a and update_b are cpp functions built in DLL using "build and reload"
       a = sfLapply(node, update_a, a, b,...) 

       sfExport("a")
       
       b = sfLapply(node, update_b, a, b,...) 

       sfExport("b")
         .
         .
         .
   }
   }))
   return(...)
}
```

Namespace:

```
export(foo)
import(RcppArmadillo)
import(rlecuyer)
import(snow)
import(rlecuyer)
importFrom("snowfall",...)
importFrom("stats","rgamma")
importFrom("stats","runif")
importFrom(Rcpp,sourceCpp)
useDynLib(mypackage, .registration=TRUE)
```

### Code outside of package

The main difference from above is that I need to:

1. Export the dependent the package to clusters/cores through `sfLibrary("Rcpp", character.only=TRUE)` and `sfLibrary("RcppArmadillo", character.only=TRUE)`.
2. Parses my cpp code via `sourceCpp(code = RcppCode)` and then load it to the clusters/cores via `sfClusterEval(sourceCpp(code = RcppCode))` where `RcppCode` contains all my cpp code as follows,

```
RcppCode = '
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

.
.
.
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List update_a(...){
.
.
.
return List::create(...)
}
.
.
.
'
```

Session Info for the dependent packages and platform:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppArmadillo_0.10.1.2.0 rlecuyer_0.3-5           Rcpp_1.0.5               snowfall_1.84-6.1        snow_0.4-3              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 parallel_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

Any suggestions on how to close the speed gap between the two are much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend to minimize to drill down.  Start with just using `RcppArmadillo`, and, if you can, the `parallel` package that comes with R.  See how the times compare.  Then add one package at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I tested it without any parallel packages and the speed between these two implementations is about the same. Next, I tried replacing the snowfall package with the native parallel, the speed discrepancy between the two still remains. So the slow down is likely due to the parallelism. Is there anything else I could do to solve this problem? Thank you again.